# Eclipse scanning through a lot of classes to find the class with the specified text

Tags: eclipse

It is possible to scan through a class for a matching result by using <kbd>Control + F</kbd>. Though if I wanted to scan through a package (or simply, a bunch of selected classes). How would I go about doing this? It doesn't let me do this in Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Within the editor, you use `Find`. Outside the editor, use `Search`. You want `File Search`, which is unaware of syntax or file types.

Comment: I find it convenient to select a folder or package in Project (or Package) Explorer and pressing Ctrl+h (Cmd+h on Mac) to bring up the Search dialog. Note that it can be used for Search/Replace too.

Comment: Strange that this just randomly showed a -15 today...and frustrating that I can't tell *why*.